# Use existing Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I was wondering is there is a way to use the existing modal popup already used by SharePoint and override its callback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, there is a dialogReturnValueCallback option when using the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx

In the callback function you can test to see whether the user clicked ok or cancel to close the dialog.

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url = url;
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

// Dialog callback
function CloseCallback(result, target) {
    if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {

    }
    if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What i want to do first is open an already existing modal creating when you install sharepoint, how can i do that ?

Comment: So you want to tap into when SharePoint opens a modal and know when it's closed?  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Yes i want to use something like, ModalDialog.Open("/UserRegister.aspx") to open already existing Sharepoint Modal

Comment: What do you mean by an already existing modal?  I don't see where my code above doesn't help you with the example you gave.  Sorry.

Comment: Sharepoint already has Modal popup defined, for when you add permissions for exemple, sharepoint will open a modal popup, i want to use the same modal popup but change its onclick and close callback.

Comment: Ahh, then I think you will need to override the ribbon behavior.  Check out SharePointRoot\template\global\xml\cmdui.xml for the correct ribbon button (your example above would be Ribbon.Permission.Add.AddUser).  Then you can create a feature that hides the ootb button and adds your own button that implements your functionality.  There are lots of examples of this on the internet.

Comment: Haha i appriciate your help but thats not it, i want to call in my page when someone clicks on a button, the same popup that is opened when you click grant permissions. Without starting from scratch.

Comment: Ahh, well, that's even easier.  Just use fiddler or something to see what url is called and replicate that in your own modal using the code I posted above.  For grant permissions it's something similar to this:

/_layouts/aclinv.aspx?obj={1D8059FF-86E5-43CE-A264-FA2ABDEB20B4},DOCLIB&List=%7B1D8059FF%2D86E5%2D43CE%2DA264%2DFA2ABDEB20B4%7D

Comment: If you need for it to be generic, you can get the needed guids using the SharePoint Client Object Model (javascript)